# hook_node_access() doesn't work for anonymous users

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I am still unable to understand what `hook_node_access()` does.
I am trying to give view access to the *Basic* content type nodes to anonymous users, but the code I wrote doesn't work, as anonymous users still get an access denied error.

```php
function modules_session_node_access($node,$op,$account) {
  $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;
  $is_anonymous = !user_is_logged_in();
  if ($op == 'view' && $is_anonymous && $type='basic') {
    return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;  
  }
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

Why doesn't that code allow anonymous users to view the *Basic* nodes?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the code. The code would grant the access to anonymous users when the operation is *view*, but for any content type.

```php
  if ($op == 'view' && $is_anonymous && $type='basic') {
    return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;  
  }
```

The last part of the `if()` statement (`&& $type='basic'`) always evaluate to `TRUE` because it's assigning `'basic'` to `$type` and that value is then "converted" into a Boolean value. (A string that isn't empty, nor `'0'`, is equivalent to `TRUE`).

The correct code would be the following one, assuming that *modules_session* is the machine name for the module implementing that hook.ì and *basic* is the content type machine name.

```php
function modules_session_node_access($node,$op,$account) {
  $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;
  if ($op == 'view' && !user_is_logged_in() && $type == 'basic') {
    return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
  }
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

That apart, `hook_node_access()` implementations aren't invoked for pages showing more than a node and when:

- The user accessing the node has the *bypass node access* permission
- The user accessing the node doesn't have the *access content* permission

In the first case, the user has the permission to access the node even if one of the `hook_node_access()` implementations wouldn't give the user the permission to access it. In the latter case, the user doesn't have the permission to access the node even if all the `hook_node_access()` implementations would give the user the permission to access it.

Even if the anonymous users would have the *access content* permission, a single `hook_node_access()` implementation giving them the permission to see a node isn't sufficient for anonymous users to see it. It's enough another `hook_node_access()` implementation returns `NODE_ACCESS_DENY` for anonymous users, and the anonymous users won't access the node.

The function invoking `hook_node_access()` is [`node_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_access/7.x), which contains the following code. (Comments are mine.)

```php
// Users with the "bypass node access" permission always have access to the node.
if (user_access('bypass node access', $account)) {
  $rights[$account->uid][$cid][$op] = TRUE;
  return TRUE;
}

// Users without the "access content" permission will never have access to the node.
if (!user_access('access content', $account)) {
  $rights[$account->uid][$cid][$op] = FALSE;
  return FALSE;
}
```

a comment after the invocation of `hook_node_access()` make clear in which case the access is granted.

> We grant access to the node if both of the following conditions are met:
>
> - No modules say to deny access.
> - At least one module says to grant access.

Then, if a node is unpublished, anonymous users cannot access it. Only the user who created it can view it, if the user has the *view own unpublished content* permission, which isn't checked when the author is the anonymous user.

```php
// Check if authors can view their own unpublished nodes.
if ($op == 'view' && !$node->status && user_access('view own unpublished content', $account) && $account->uid == $node->uid && $account->uid != 0) {
  $rights[$account->uid][$cid][$op] = TRUE;
  return TRUE;
}
```